# Looking for simple integration of scripts to Excel similar to Google Apps Scripts

Tags: excel, office-scripts

I've been used to using Google Suite and therefore also Google Sheets + Apps Scripts.

Now I got a new project where I will need to work with Excel. I've already digged quite a bit, but I dont have the feeling that I found the easiest integration yet.

I found so far:

1. VS Code + Node.js + Yeoman
2. Script Lab (it fails to load so I would like to get something more reliable)

Is there any other way that works similar to VBA but is JS-based?

Comment: For coding, if you understand the logic of the original then re-write that logic in the new code.

Comment: For the VSC Solution I dont understand how to connect the Excel Sheet with the Script. After running "yo office" as accordning to the wiki, it always creates a new excel file.

Comment: You could try Office Scripts but its currently only available in Excel online with an M365 E3 or E4 subscription. ScriptLab is the simplest desktop JS solution - I suggest troubleshooting the load failure.

Comment: There are two different JavaScript APIs available for Excel. The Excel JavaScript API in Office.js and Office Scripts. VS Code, Node, Yeoman, and ScriptLab all use Office.js. To use Office Scripts you need to create the script in Excel Online. You can read more about using Office Scripts here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/overview/excel